# Google::Chart with perl

Tags: perl, google-visualization

I want to create a graph in perl, I've found Google::Chart module, it looks very good. Everytime I try to install it manually, I have a lot of errors, the install fails. I guess I should install the dependencies:

```
Warning: prerequisite Class::MOP 0.63 not found.
Warning: prerequisite LWP::UserAgent 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Moose 0.54 not found.
Writing Makefile for Google::Chart
Writing MYMETA.yml
```

But for example if I try to the make Moose files, it says Failed 391/393 test programs. 12/13 subtests failed.

Is there a basic pack of modules, which should be installed, or what should I install to use Google::Chart?

I use it on Linux Mint 15

Edit:

The error log:

```
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'inc', 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t

#   Failed test 'use Google::Chart::Color;'
#   at /root/.cpanm/work/1380630794.4539/Google-Chart-0.05014/inc/Test/UseAllModules.pm line 69.
#     Tried to use 'Google::Chart::Color'.
#     Error:  The type constraint 'Google::Chart::Color::Data' has already been created in Google::Chart::Fill::LinearStripes::Stripe and cannot be created again in Google::Chart::Color at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/Moose/Util/TypeConstraints.pm line 541.
#   Moose::Util::TypeConstraints::_create_type_constraint("Google::Chart::Color::Data", "Str", CODE(0x2cfb8d0), CODE(0x2d02c88), undef, undef) called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/Moose/Util/TypeConstraints.pm line 361
#   Moose::Util::TypeConstraints::subtype("Google::Chart::Color::Data", HASH(0x2cfb930), HASH(0x2ccb420), HASH(0x2cedab0)) called at lib/Google/Chart/Color.pm line 32
#   require Google/Chart/Color.pm called at (eval 353) line 2
#   Test::UseAllModules::BEGIN() called at lib/Google/Chart/Color.pm line 0
#   eval {...} called at lib/Google/Chart/Color.pm line 0
#   eval 'package Test::UseAllModules;
# use Google::Chart::Color @{$args[0]};
# 1;
# 
# ;' called at /usr/share/perl/5.14/Test/More.pm line 885
#   Test::More::_eval("package Test::UseAllModules;\x{a}use Google::Chart::Color \@{\$args"..., ARRAY(0x1d29508)) called at /usr/share/perl/5.14/Test/More.pm line 860
#   Test::More::use_ok("Google::Chart::Color") called at /root/.cpanm/work/1380630794.4539/Google-Chart-0.05014/inc/Test/UseAllModules.pm line 69
#   Test::UseAllModules::all_uses_ok() called at t/00_compile.t line 4
#   main::BEGIN() called at lib/Google/Chart/Color.pm line 0
#   eval {...} called at lib/Google/Chart/Color.pm line 0
# Compilation failed in require at (eval 353) line 2.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 353) line 2.

#   Failed test 'use Google::Chart;'
#   at /root/.cpanm/work/1380630794.4539/Google-Chart-0.05014/inc/Test/UseAllModules.pm line 69.
#     Tried to use 'Google::Chart'.
#     Error:  Attempt to reload Google/Chart/Color.pm aborted.
# Compilation failed in require at lib/Google/Chart.pm line 9.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at lib/Google/Chart.pm line 9.
# Compilation failed in require at (eval 354) line 2.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 354) line 2.

#   Failed test 'use Google::Chart::Marker;'
#   at /root/.cpanm/work/1380630794.4539/Google-Chart-0.05014/inc/Test/UseAllModules.pm line 69.
#     Tried to use 'Google::Chart::Marker'.
#     Error:  Attempt to reload Google/Chart/Color.pm aborted.
# Compilation failed in require at lib/Google/Chart/Marker.pm line 68.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at lib/Google/Chart/Marker.pm line 68.
# Compilation failed in require at (eval 382) line 2.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 382) line 2.
Bailout called.  Further testing stopped:  failed: Google::Chart::Color,Google::Chart,Google::Chart::Marker
FAILED--Further testing stopped: failed: Google::Chart::Color,Google::Chart,Google::Chart::Marker
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
-> FAIL Installing Google::Chart failed. See /root/.cpanm/build.log for details.
```

Comment: Why are you installing manually? And what `perl` version are you using? Use `cpan` or `cpanm`, then: `cpanm Google::Chart` – takes care of installing all dependencies, similar to `apt-get`. If you are using the perl that ships with Mint, you can also install modules from the package manager, e.g. `sudo apt-get install libmoose-perl` (probably out of date).

Comment: I got this error, with the cpanm Google::Chart command: Building and testing Google-Chart-0.05014 ... FAIL
! Installing Google::Chart failed. See /root/.cpanm/build.log for details.
45 distributions installed

Comment: That is progress! Now run the command again, and edit the resulting error log at that path into your question, so that we can see what went wrong.

Comment: That is ugly (oh, and I can reproduce with my perl 5.18.1). It seems to be a bug, which you could [file](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Google-Chart). Sadly, the last bug was resolved 4 years ago, so it seems this module is a bit unmaintained. It may be better to find another module that meets your requirements.

Comment: Could you suggest me an another modul which can dynamically draw a chart?

Comment: What kind of charts? Do you need interactivity? Depending on what you are trying to do, the Gnuplot or GD bindings might be sufficient.

Comment: I have two arrays, with changing values, I want to draw them out. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38430/discussion-between-amon-and-erbal)